# Linkedin parseq. How to run task after task?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, linkedin-api, parseq

I'm using [parseq](https://github.com/linkedin/parseq) framework for asynchronous computation.

Consider the following code. It first queries the content of google.com and then map the content to it's length. Finally, the length is printed.

The problem is that only the first task is ran. Why?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        final int numCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final ExecutorService taskScheduler = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCores + 1);
        final ScheduledExecutorService timerScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numCores + 1);

        final Engine engine = new EngineBuilder()
                .setTaskExecutor(taskScheduler)
                .setTimerScheduler(timerScheduler)
                .build();

        Task<Integer> task = Task.async(() -> {
            SettablePromise<String> promise = Promises.settable();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://google.com")
                    .build();

            okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    promise.done(response.body().string());
                }
            });

            return promise;

        }).map("map content to length", content -> content.length())
                .andThen(System.out::println);

        engine.blockingRun(task);
        engine.blockingRun(task);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve your problem with the use of `HttpClient` instead of `OkHttp` .

Below are the overall maven dependencies that i used for this code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.linkedin.parseq</groupId>
    <artifactId>parseq</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.linkedin.parseq</groupId>
    <artifactId>parseq-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
import com.linkedin.parseq.Engine;
import com.linkedin.parseq.EngineBuilder;
import com.linkedin.parseq.Task;
import com.linkedin.parseq.httpclient.HttpClient;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

public class Main  {
    private static Task<Integer> fetchBody(String url) {
        Task<Integer> map = HttpClient.get(url).task().map("map content to length", content -> content.getResponseBody().length());
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int numCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final ExecutorService taskScheduler = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCores + 1);
        final ScheduledExecutorService timerScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numCores + 1);
        final Engine engine = new EngineBuilder()
                .setTaskExecutor(taskScheduler)
                .setTimerScheduler(timerScheduler)
                .build();
        final Task<Integer> stackOverFlow = fetchBody("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        final Task<Integer> google = fetchBody("http://www.google.com");
        final Task<Integer> ethereum = fetchBody("http://ethereum.stackexchange.com");
        final Task<String> plan = Task.par(stackOverFlow, google, ethereum)
                .map((s, g, e) -> "StackOverFlow Page: " + s + " \n" +
                        "Google Page: " + g + "\n" +
                        "Ethereum Page: " + e + "\n")
                .andThen(System.out::println);
        engine.run(plan);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
StackOverFlow Page: 149 
Google Page: 13097
Ethereum Page: 152
```

> This example is fully asynchronous. The home pages for StackOverflow ,
>   Google, and Ethereum are all fetched in parallel while the original
>   thread has returned to the calling code. We used Tasks.par to tell the
>   engine to parallelize these HTTP requests. Once all of the responses
>   have been retrieved they are transformed into a `int` (string
>   length)that is finally printed out.

**Gist**: https://gist.github.com/vishwaratna/26417f7467a4e827eadeee6923ddf3ae

Answer (score 1):

beacause you use **the same task** to run.

Task is interface , and the abstract class is BaseTask which contains the filed "**_stateRef**", this filed maintain the task status.

first run the task in the INIT status, when the first has excute.  status change to RUN.
in this code prevent the task excute.
com.linkedin.parseq.BaseTask#contextRun

has a judgement:**transitionRun(traceBuilder)**.

so，the right way to excute the code is follow:

```
 private void replayOkHttpNotExecuteSecondTask() {
    try {
        log.info("begin task");
        engine.blockingRun(okHttpTask());
        engine.blockingRun(okHttpTask());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private Task okHttpTask() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    return Task.async(() -> {
        SettablePromise<String> settablePromise = Promises.settable();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://baidu.com").build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                settablePromise.done(response.body().string());
            }
        });
        return settablePromise;
    }).map("map to length", content -> content.length())
            .andThen(System.out::println);
}
```